# Can you paint textures in Blender 2.8x with values > 1? (I.e. HDR)

Tags: texture-painting

Is it possible to paint a texture with values greater than 1? I'd like to paint some emissive surfaces to use as lights, and I need large values. It seems the color picker only goes to RGB=1.0. Am I missing something?
(I know I can import an .exr from outside Blender. I'm talking about the texture painting inside Blender.)

As a fallback, I can paint the textures with <1 values and use a math node. But I'd like to paint them as they should be.

Comment: I don't believe you can use values outside 0,1 in texture painting.  But you *can* set up a material to multiply your RGB values by any value you want and then bake to an .exr.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to paint them as they should be.

Not really sure what that means. Art is trickery. The only rule is, "if it looks good, it is good".

That being said, one way to do what you want would be to texture paint on an image, assign that as the color input to an Emission node, and crank the Emission node strength up to 200 or whatever.

If you feel fancy, you could add multiple textures to a single object with a Mix Shader.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well, to be pedantic, "as they should be" means, in a linear workflow, the correct amount of light emitted from each pixel of the texture in lux, when used at a predetermined scale. But I take your point; since it seems the color picker only goes to 1, using a vector math node or emission (what's the difference?) to scale it up is OK.

Comment: @GaryO Usually you can enter values higher than 1.0, by manually typing into the fields. Currently on mobile, therefore I couldn't check if that's the case for the texture painting area.

Comment: @RobertGützkow You can't in the color picker for the texture painter brush.